# Dependency injection have two instances of same dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I've been struggling with a small DI problem, that I think should be very easy to solve, but for some reason I can't find the solution.

I have a service that should one one DI object in the same way for two different things.

```
public class EquationManager : IEquationManager
{
       private readonly IEquationEvaluator _equationEvaluator;
       private readonly IEquationEvaluator _inversEquationEvaluator;
    
       public EquationManager(IEquationEvaluator equationEvaluator)
       {
           _equationEvaluator = equationEvaluator;
           _inversEquationEvaluator = equationEvaluator;
       }
}
```

So what I would need is 2 instances of the same DI. That's all. If I write the code as it is, they are shallow copies, what ever I set to _inversEquationEvaluator  is also updated in _equationEvaluator  ( which is normal).

How do I have 2 separate instances of the same DI? Is this possible in a simple way. I would like to avoid registering `IEquationEvaluator` in 2 different ways in the container.

My second question: is my architecture wrong? What I want to achieve here is having an math equation that takes an input parameter (`int`) and output a double value. I need now a way to revert this process using an other equation. So I input a double value and in theory I should obtain an int value. `IEquationEvaluator` is a class that deals with the math operation.

Comment: Why don't you these two equations in two methods in the class that implemented IEquationEvaluator?

Comment: Well because all of the follow the same process. Get result. IEquationEvaluator would then have duplicate data. IT should be abstract. Equation and InversEquation are basically  the same, I just have to use them in different ways.

Comment: Could you show (in code) how you plan to use those two `IEquationEvaluator`? It's not clear why you need two instances of the same type to achieve what you need.

Comment: How do you register _IEquationEvaluator_ implementation?

Comment: What do you mean by "should one one DI object"? What do you mean by "of the same DI"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
 public enum EquationEvaluatorType
    {
        EquationEvaluator,
        InversEquationEvaluator
    }


    public interface IEquationEvaluator
    {
        public EquationEvaluatorType Type { get; }

        //your methods and properties
    }

    public class EquationEvaluator : IEquationEvaluator
    {
        public EquationEvaluatorType Type => EquationEvaluatorType.EquationEvaluator;
    }

    public class InversEquationEvaluator : IEquationEvaluator
    {
        public EquationEvaluatorType Type => EquationEvaluatorType.InversEquationEvaluator;
    }

    public class EquationManager : IEquationManager
    {
        private readonly IEquationEvaluator _equationEvaluator;
        private readonly IEquationEvaluator _inversEquationEvaluator;

        public EquationManager(IEnumerable<IEquationEvaluator> items)
        {
            _equationEvaluator = items.First(x=>x.Type==EquationEvaluatorType.EquationEvaluator);
            _inversEquationEvaluator = items.First(x => x.Type == EquationEvaluatorType.InversEquationEvaluator);
        }
    }
```

And in your startup:

```
  services.AddScoped<IEquationEvaluator, EquationEvaluator>();
  services.AddScoped<IEquationEvaluator, InversEquationEvaluator>();
```

Comment: This works, I was hoping for "less code" for such a simple outcome I need, but at the end I had to do it like this. Thank you!.